# Best way to set value a List boolean

Tags: c#

I'd like to set value in List Boolean.

like this:

```
List<bool> items = new List<bool> { false, false, false };

for(int i=0; i<items.count; i++)
{
   items[i] = true;
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
items.ForEach(c=> c = true);
```

Is there a good way?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot change the iteration variable with a foreach-loop

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have? It seems like a good enough way to me.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to allocate new memory or set to index one by one.
It's not a problem at the moment, but it's a question of whether there's a good way

Comment: There is no way to do this without allocating new memory or setting the value by index. Fabio has provided several good options, but none will meet your requirements.

Comment: _I don't think it's a good idea to allocate new memory or set to index one by one._ - allocating memory for new list with updated values or updating existing instance is a trade-off choice you can do based on the usage.  Updating values by index - you must access every item memory to update it with new value, so you need to calculate memory address for every item by yourself - where you end up with same approach array index already provide ;)

Comment: The first example works and it is perfectly clear and doesn't have the side effect to create a new list. The second one cannot work because  you have a value type in your list so you are assigning true to a different variable

Comment: updating the items in-place doesn't allocate new memory... :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create new array with same values you can use [Enumerable.Repeat(TResult, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=netframework-4.8)

```
List<bool> items = new List<bool> { false, false, false };
var allTrue = Enumerable.Repeat(true, items.Count)
```

To update values of existed instance of `List`, you must access every item it by `index`

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    items[i] = true;
}
```

if you are using this a lot, wrap loop with an extension method

```
public static void UpdateAll<T>(this List<T> items, T newValue)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        items[i] = newValue;
    }
}

// Usage

var items = new List<bool> { false, false, false };

items.UpdateAll(true);
```

But in most of the cases, creating new list with updated  values will be most convenient approach.

```
var items = new List<bool> { false, true, false };
var updated = items.Select(item => true).ToList(); // true, true, true

// Or with some logic
var updated = items.Select(item => !item).ToList(); // true, false, true
```

Comment: I recommended the last approach but got downvoted. Your answer is much better and deserves and upvote :).

Comment: You could have a lot of reasons to not create a new list. For example, if the list is really big, or if some part of your code has a reference to the original list and use that original list for its scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop as you mentioned but ForEach loop is not working because iteration variable of a foreach-loop is *read-only*.